# Azure Data Facory, encoding issues

Tags: sql-server, oracle, azure, encoding, azure-data-factory

I'm currently working on a project on Azure data Factory and i have some issues with, I think, encoding.
I did'nt managed to find anything on the documentation, you have maybe the answer?

I'm trying to make a flow of data between SQL Server and Oracle.
The fields in my source table on SQL Server are nvarchar(255).

In order to make the flow working, i have to configure the target field in Varchar2(255). If i try to put nvarchar(255) the flow fall with error :

```
ERROR [22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]String data&#44; right truncated.
```

Otherwise, with Varchar2(255) it work fine.

But! My issues come with spécial characters:

if in my data source, there is an accent like ('é','è','à'), the flow fall with error:

```
ERROR [22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]String data&#44; right truncated.
```

I try to make the target field longer, to add a substring to my selection request but it doesn't work. I can't transfer the spécial characters...

(btw i tried to do an "insert into" with the the values of my request directly in the oracle data base and it works fine).

The SQL Server is configure with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
THe oracle database is configure in AL16UTF16  with version 11.2.0.4.0.

Did you have any idea or suggestions to solve that issue?
Have a great day!

Comment: What do you mean by "The oracle database is configure in AL16UTF16"? In Oracle you have 2 characters sets, the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`. For `VARCHAR2` columns the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` takes place.

Comment: My bad: NLS_CHARACTERSET -> AL32UTF8  and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET->AL16UTF16

Comment: Did you try to set `NLS_LANG=.WE8ISO8859P1` environment variable on your SQL Server?

Comment: I did more test, apparently, i can insert special character. But Juste 1.
If i try to insert 'é', it's ok . But 'éé' is not ok.

Do you have some explications?

Comment: In deed this look very strange. I have no idea.

Comment: I finally have a answer to this problem. It was an error in the driver of the integration runtime. It's now fixed, so problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue in Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime, and has been fixed in the latest version.  You may want to upgrade your Integration Runtime and have a retry.